# Regarding <Results> Element/propery/Tag/Function in DataPower xslt

Tags: xslt, ibm-datapower

This may be somewhat naive but I am quite struck on the issue

There is a specific `<result>` element in DataPower and when calling through xslt we have somewhat following format(which I discovered in some forums)--

```
<results mode="require-all" multiple-outputs="true" transactional="true" retry-interval="100" asynchronous="false">
  <url input="var://the_request_SOAP_Format"asynchronous="true">https://XXXXXXX</url>
```

now in this (url input)  is the request which needs to be send and (https://XXXXXXX) is the specified backend where it needs to be sent

Now I have some authentication headers(httpHeaders) also which I need to send without which I will get Authorization error

```
    <xsl:variable name="httpHeaders">
      <header name="Content-Type">application/json</header>
      <header name="Authorization">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('Bearer ',$some_sessionID)"/>
      </header>
    </xsl:variable>
```

Is this possible to add these 'httpHeaders'  in the result mode element/Tab property

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve but adding http headers for the response (backside) you do with:

```
<dp:set-http-response-header name="'HeaderName'" value="$httpHeaders"/>
```

or

```
<dp:set-http-request-header name="'HeaderName'" value="$httpHeaders"/>
```

The `<results>` is the collection of data that the Processing Policy will output as Payload for the Request/Response and won't contain headers. You shouldn't try to alter the `<results>` object!

Answer (score 0):

The "results-doc" method of calling backends is quite powerful, but I'm not sure from your question if you fully understand it.  The url/@input attribute needs to be a DataPower context:

```
<url input="var://context/mycontext" ...
```

To associate headers with that context, you should do something like this for each header you need:

```
<dp:set-variable
  name="'var://context/mycontext/_extension/header/Content-Type'"
  value="'application/json'"/>
```

(This would be done in your XSLT code, separate from creating the "results" document, but before you use a Results Action to execute.)